# Query displays different data each time I run it in Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following query:

```
SELECT pr_production_units_details.id AS idProductionUnit, 
pr_production_units_details.production_units_detail AS productionUnit,
IF(pr_varieties.variety IS NULL, 'SIN SEMBRAR O ERR', pr_varieties.variety) 
AS variety
FROM pr_production_units_details
LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS ids, sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail,  
sw_sowing.id_variety
FROM sw_sowing
WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
GROUP BY sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail, id_variety
ORDER BY ids DESC
) AS sw 

ON pr_production_units_details.id = sw.id_production_unit_detail
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON sw.id_variety = pr_varieties.id
WHERE pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail = 1
AND pr_production_units_details.status = 100
AND pr_production_units_details.id_tenant = 1
GROUP BY pr_production_units_details.id
```

which brings me the following result:

```
------------------------------------------------
  idProductionUnit | productionUnit |  variety
------------------------------------------------
        1          |        1       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        2          |        2       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        3          |        3       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
```

The above result is fine, but every time I run the query, the variety column changes its values, that is:

```
------------------------------------------------
  idProductionUnit | productionUnit |  variety
------------------------------------------------
        1          |        1       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        2          |        2       |   BLUE 
------------------------------------------------
        3          |        3       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
```

also it gives me the following result:

```
------------------------------------------------
  idProductionUnit | productionUnit |  variety
------------------------------------------------
        1          |        1       |   BLUE 
------------------------------------------------
        2          |        2       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
        3          |        3       |   YELLOW 
------------------------------------------------
```

I do not know if it has to be seen by the ORDER BY or the GROUP BY but I have not understood because it shows me different data.

I hope that you can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Like @jarlh said, you must use an aggregate function or group by on all in the select column list

Comment: I am sorry I am new in mysql can you give me an example please! @jarlh

Comment: Just read my comment, and do what the general rule says!

Comment: what results do you get if you remove your sub join?

Comment: If I remove the sub join I cannot get the variety, because it is the way that I use to get them @RyanGadsdon

Comment: It likely the sub join that is causing the different results. i would try and order  it all at the end as opposed to in the sub join

Comment: I know that the problem is about the sub join I am traying to improve the query @RyanGadsdon

Comment: @FabianSierra have you tried ordering it after the sub join?

Comment: Yes I tried but it doesn't work! @RyanGadsdon

Comment: if you create it in sql fiddle i could have a look and i would be able to test it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve my problem, I change the query like this:

```
SELECT  pr_production_units_details.id AS idProductionUnit, pr_production_units_details.production_units_detail AS  productionUnit, pr_varieties.variety
FROM (SELECT MAX(sw_sowing.id) AS id
            FROM sw_sowing
            WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0
            AND sw_sowing.id_tenant = 1
            AND YEARWEEK(sw_sowing.date) <= 201741
            GROUP BY  sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
)AS sw
INNER JOIN sw_sowing ON sw_sowing.id = sw.id
INNER JOIN pr_production_units_details ON pr_production_units_details.id = sw_sowing.id_production_unit_detail
INNER JOIN pr_varieties ON pr_varieties.id = sw_sowing.id_variety
WHERE sw_sowing.status != 0 
AND sw_sowing.id_tenant =1
AND pr_production_units_details.id_grouper_detail = 13
GROUP BY pr_production_units_details.id, variety
```

I follow the instructions about the comments and my error only shows me depending the Mysql versions

Thanks for the help!